# Writing logs AzureCosmosDB via SeriLog: Partition Key

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, serilog

I'm writing logs to AzureDocumentDB via SeriLog. It looks like SeriLog already has it's own log structure and all the custom fields are placed under the **Properties** field (Please check the attachment).

In that case how do I use a custom field as my database partition key?

When I use **/Properties/UserId** as my partition key, all the logs get rejected by CosmosDB saying **partition key value must be supplied for this operation**. How do I specify UserId as the partition key?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]
Updated: 
I used ILogger instance to write the log. Example:

**logger.LogInformation("Session completed: {@SessionCompleteEvent}", sessionCompleteEvent);**

Serilog application settings:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "WriteTo": {
      "CosmosDB": {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "StartsWith(@Properties['SourceContext'] , 'MyApp')"
                }
              }
            ],
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "AzureDocumentDB",
                "Args": {
                  "endpointUrl": "https://analytics-test.documents.azure.com:345/",
                  "authorizationKey": "app_key",
                  "databaseName": "db0",
                  "collectionName": "my_app",
                  "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share some your codes with us? (for example: how you log the request, how you add the SeriLog, and what the UserId is).

Comment: Hi Jack, I updated my question with my SeriLog configuration. Please check above.

Answer (score 1):

> partition key value must be supplied for this operation

Based on this error, you need to specify the partition key setting in the requestOptions when you insert documents into partitioned collection.Please refer to my sample code:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly string endpointUrl = "https://***.documents.azure.com:443/";
        private static readonly string authorizationKey = "***";
        private static readonly string databaseId = "db";
        private static readonly string collectionId = "coll";

        private static DocumentClient client;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            QueryTest();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        public static async void QueryTest()

        {
            client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpointUrl), authorizationKey);
            var uri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, collectionId);


            Pojo pojo = new Pojo();
            pojo.name = "Name";
            pojo.Properties = new Properties();
            pojo.Properties.UserId = "123";

            RequestOptions request = new RequestOptions();
            request.PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("123");

            await client.CreateDocumentAsync(uri, pojo, request,false);
        }
    }
    class Pojo : Document
    {
        public Properties Properties { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    class Properties
    {

        public string UserId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

Update Answer:

Dig deep into the source code of [SeriLog AzureDocumentDB sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-azuredocumentdb/tree/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.AzureDocumentDb/Sinks/AzureDocumentDb) which mentioned in your comment,found that the import operation is implemented by executing [bulk import js](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-azuredocumentdb/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.AzureDocumentDb/Sinks/AzureDocumentDb/bulkImport.js) stored procedure.

```
try {
                SelfLog.WriteLine($"Sending batch of {logEventsBatch.Count} messages to DocumentDB");
                var storedProcedureResponse = await _client
                                                   .ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<int>(_bulkStoredProcedureLink, args)
                                                   .ConfigureAwait(false);
                SelfLog.WriteLine(storedProcedureResponse.StatusCode.ToString());

                return storedProcedureResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
            }
```

However, according to my research and test, bulk import js only supports single partition collections. Please see below threads,they met the same error as yours:

1.https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-datamigrationtool/issues/47

2.https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-datamigrationtool/issues/64

So,i'm afraid that you have to follow the [.net executor lib](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/cosmos-db/bulk-executor-dot-net) to modify the import code of `SeriLog AzureDocumentDB sink` by yourself.

Comment: Thanks Jay. But, I don't use Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client. As I mentioned in my original question, SeriLog AzureDocumentDB sink is used to send logs to CosmosDB. I want to know how to specify the partition key with SeriLog.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this Jay. It looks like I might have to switch to `Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client`. I prefer SeriLog, so I can manage all my logs through a single central hub. But, partition key issue a deal breaker.

Comment: @OrangeTree the bulk import part convert into .net bulk executor will not change the management of SeriLog. Because according to the source code,it seems that the bulk operation is supported by the bulk import js stored procedure. So i'm afraid that you can't avoid this unless it supports partitioned collection bulk import originally.

Comment: @OrangeTree Surely,you could wait for others' ideas if someone could provide better solution.

Comment: @OrangeTree I think the key of this case is how does the underlying code output data to Cosmos. Anyway,the insert operation is based on the REST API.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this @jay-gong. It's strange that SeriLog doesn't have this for CosmosDB. Some other sinks like Serilog.Sinks.AzureTableStorage has it's own keyGenerator implementation.